# How to style/customise the grub menu?

Tags: grub2

I want to style up the default grub menu to something like we get in windows 8 dual booted with ubuntu. Want to make a GUI for grub menu. i saw its possible somewhere so I want to know how. I have Windows 7 ultimate dual booted with ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this article from `Arch Wiki` very useful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks

What I got out of that article for my modest needs is setting wallpaper/background:

add line `GRUB_BACKGROUND=/path/to/your/image.jpg` into `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub`. Personally I use `GRUB_BACKGROUND=/usr/share/backgrounds/Foggy_Forest_by_Jake_Stewart.jpg` which is one of the default wallpapers